# Parallel lines as generalised circles in inversive geometry

Tags: inversive-geometry

[image] Consider the inversion of circles ($w_1$ and $w_2$) w.r.t. the circle ($c$) that gives circles of infinite radius ($t_1$ and $t_2$ respectively).
What is the nature of the generalised circles $t_1$ and $t_2$ (are they intersecting at one point OR concentric)?
Is it possible to get $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that they are concentric circles of infinite radius?

Comment: Can we say that the parallel lines t1 and t2 meet at a point at infinity ?

Comment: Yes inversion moves the center of the inversion circle to infinity

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Is there a concept such as concentric circles of infinite radius( if we imagine the circle t1 to be moved half the distance between t1 and t2 ,then we ge t two concentric circles of infinite radius).

Comment: Not sure but there is something like the angle between the circles w1 and w2 in your example they are tangent to each other so the lines are parallel